# Is there a way to screen record with 1000fps?

Tags: video-recording, digital-recording, recording, video-game

I'm looking for software that can screen record (windows 10) at 1000fps. I will record a game and want to take timings and I need 1000fps at least. I don't care if the game doesn't reach that 1000fps i want the software. Don't say "uhh u cant record a game with 1000fps and not be laggy", shutup i dont care i only need the software

Comment: Can you explain why you want 1000fps, when the fastest gaming monitors have a refresh rate of 240Hz...

Comment: @DrMayhemYou are the dissapointment i mentioned..

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be mad, we're only helping :D

Yes, there is software out there that does that. Try:

- Open Broadcast (obs)
- Fraps (although I personally hate it)
- Streamlabs (basically obs but in a different color)

If you want to have absolute and full control over what you're recording and encoding without having to juggle 3rd party software, you could try using ffmpeg and recording the screen via commands. A very helpful and valuable guide can be found here:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

Comment: yea sorry for being mad but i am tired of seeing useless comments like "uh u cant record in more fps than ur in game fps" yea but u actually helped so thank you. Can you tell me where i can set it up to record with more fps ?

Comment: Sure thing, that would depend on the program you're using. I believe it's a good idea if you look into the documentation for the program of your choice, as you should also consider bitrate, progressive vs. interlaces, color spaces, etc. when dealing with such a high framerate (mostly due to filesize). May I ask what you're planning to do?

Comment: I want to record a game so i can translate the frames of the video to milliseconds, and i want to record with 1000fps because it will be easier for me to make this happen. I will most likely capture it in 144p or something low so it doesnt eat my storage i just need the high framerate not the quality its not gonna be public or somehing

Comment: I doubt that this will work properly. In order to translate frames to milliseconds, the game would have to be running at 1000 fps as well. Just capturing 1000fps of some 250fps gameplay will give you many frames that contain the same still-image. Maybe it will work if you set the resolution of the game to something ridiculously low as well, but even then I am not optimistic. Which game are you trying to do this for? I assume it has something to do with precise measurements of some sort?